# How can I use or create a pagination in REST API in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rest

I would like to create a pagination in Rest API for Laravel. I want pagination like, Suppose I have total 30 categories in Database & I want to display 10 items in each page So total page will be 3 and 10 items will display in each page.

I have used `paginate()` method but it's only showing items by given number , I used below the script but it's not provided output that I mentioned.

```
$getCategories = Category::paginate();
$listCat = array();
    foreach($getCategories as $val){
        $cateName['id'] = $val->id;
        $cateName['name'] = $val->name;
        $cateName['description'] = $val->description;
        $cateName['image'] = url('/').'/public/assets/images/category/'.$val->image;
        $listCat[] = $cateName;
    }
    
    if(!empty($listCat)){
        $respons['status'] = 'true';
        $respons['message'] = 'Categories list';
        $respons['data list']=$listCat;
    }else{
       $respons['status'] = 'false';
       $respons['message'] = 'Category is not found.'; 
    }
return Response::json($respons,200);
```

Does anybody tell me how could i use pagination in Rest Api?

I got output like..

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

for REST pagination you can use code like this

```
    $data = Category::paginate(request()->all());    
    return Response::json($data, 200);
```

then you will see at the bottom of data, they will show the pagination info for you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use LengthAwarePaginator to generate the laravel pagination links here is an example:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
```

then:

```
public function getPosts(Request $request){

   //First resolve the current page
   $page = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
   //Define how many items you want to display per page
   $perPage = 15;

   //Call the external API and retrieve the data passing the $page and the $perPage

   $response = Http::get('https://api.example.com/posts', [
       'page' => $page,
       'per_page' => $perPage,
   ]);
   $data = $response->json();

   //Create a new LengthAwarePaginator instance
   $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($data['items'], $data['total'],   $perPage, $page, [
    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
   ]);

   //Pass the paginator instance to your Blade view
   return view('items', ['items' => $paginator]);
});
```

In your Blade view, you can use the $posts variable like a regular paginator instance and use methods like links() to generate pagination links:

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <li>{{ $post['name'] }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

 {{ $posts->links() }}
```

Comment: It works but you should render the $items on the blade

Answer (score 0):

**you need to turn your pagination or pagination instance to json to get the data of you pagination**

just as @Kotzilla answer it for you but i'm providing the answer that worked for me

this is done from your controller or from the place you call your query from .
and this is what you did in your example
but ....

`$getCategories = Category::paginate(10)->response()->getData(true);`

this will return your pagination data in your response

Answer (score -2):

After this:

```
$getCategories = Category::All();
$categories = DB::table('category')->paginate($pageNumber);
```

Return it as:

```
return response()->json($categories, 200);
```

In your json response you will see `"next_page_url"` to go second page or vice versa `"prev_page_url"`.

Comment: I am not talking about to use in blade template I already mentioned that I want pagination in API ( Rest API).

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show the expected result as a json?

Answer (score -5):

it's simple

```
---------use this in your controller---------
$categories = DB::table('category')
->paginate(3);

 return view('your_view_here',[
'categories' => $categories,
]);


-----------in your views file----------

@foreach($categories as $category)

{{$category-id}}

@endforeach

  <span>{{ $categories->appends(request()->input())->links() }}</span>
```

the span code is the paginate buttons

hope it will help u

Comment: I am not talking about to use in blade template I already mentioned that I want pagination in API ( Rest API).